# Storing custom information in an audio/mp3 file

Tags: file, tags, mp3, id3

I want to store some custom information (tags) in a mp3 file (or even better, in any audio file, but mp3 would be a start).

What would be a good way to do that?
ID3? If yes, in what ID3-Section should that be (it shouldn't be overwritten by other programs). I thought of the "comment" section, but it is overwritten quite frequently, I think.

Is there an easy way to store information to any audio file?

**UPDATE:**
I decided to store the information into a custom ID3 Tag (with my own name) via the [MyID3](http://www.fightingquaker.com/myid3/) library :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends: If you want to use this custom information only for your own collection, you can store it to whatever tag you like.
 If you hope that your custom information can be read by (nearly) all popular music management tools, I suggest that you store it to the defined tags according the [ID3v2.3](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0) standard.

If your custom information doesn't fit into one of this tags, lets assume an example like: "eye color of the lead singer", you could make your own private tag. This is noted in 4.28 private frame with the description:

> This frame is used to contain information from a software producer that its program uses and does not fit into the other frames.